# Display maximum possible count of sites in footer

Tags: feature-request, support, footer

New collapsing/expanding footer displays sites by catecories. E.g. **Technology** section is most solid and contains more then five columns each of them contains seven sites:

> [image: technology]

Other sections like **Science** have less items, only two non-full columns and **more(10)** link:

> [image: science]

Seems there is possible to display all of science sites, so **more** link will not be actually needed.

Why the list of sites here is intentionally reduced? Is it possible to show all of them in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the list of sites here is intentionally reduced?

Part of graduation is getting a place in the footer.

The "more" link goes to all sites in a category - graduated as well as sites in public beta.

Comment: Why not to display beta sites in the footer too?

Comment: Because getting a place in the footer is a graduation privilege for a site. Beta sites have not graduated, so no place in the footer.

Comment: @alexolut By definition, a beta site is still growing and not completely defined. It would not be right to direct a bunch of traffic from more well-established sites to a beta site, which is why we also don't allow migration targets to beta sites. Until they've defined their site and proven they can stand on their own, we avoid doing things that might end up damaging their site instead.

Comment: @animuson thanks for explanation. If this were possible I would accept your comment as answer!