# Why there are no non-English sites in the footer?

Tags: support, localization, footer, russian-stackoverflow, graduating-sites

According to Oded's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299609/339911):

> Part of graduation is getting a place in the footer.

Graduated sites should be presented in the footer. But I can't find there sites like *Stack Overflow in Russian*, *Stack Overflow in Portuguese*, *Stack Overflow in Spanish* ...

> [image: footer]

Why are such sites absent from the footer?

Comment: Probably for the same reason those aren't on the Hot Network Questions list?

Comment: They are behind **"more (26)"**.

Comment: @D-side **more** link is used mostly for non-graduated sites as far as I undertand.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it indeed.

Comment: @rene HNQ list contains titles that could not be understood by English-spoken users and I can agree with this decision. But site name could be displayed in English (or even added to translation DB to provide language dependent version for non-English sites).

Comment: Yeah, it was only speculation from my side. I'm keen to learn the SE staff response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the actual reason, but now non-English graduated sites are presented in the footer:

> [image: Footer]

Thanks to the developers for justice.