# Site names are partially obscured in the footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer

Site names are partially obscured in the footer for the Technology section:

> [image: footer]

Seems it happened after [adding localized sites in that section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299752/339911).

Comment: @redhand this also appears to be happening on my 1080p desktop screen. It's not a mobile only issue.

Comment: There's good reasons to use full sites in mobile view - moderation tools for example . I have the same thing happening on a OP3 on chrome. lemme see if I can find a supported system, ... It happens on my windows 10 system on firefox 55.0.3 on a full screen too. I think "this is a problem with you" is... unfair. Alexlut should probably edit his question though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see this is fixed now and should be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

> [image: fixed footer]