# Why would the number of columns in the "Stack Exchange Network" section in the footer vary?

Tags: discussion, design, footer

The number of columns in the "Stack Exchange Network" in the footer varies. For example, the Science section has 2 columns, but there are still 10 more unlisted sites. Why don't they be listed? Apparently there are rooms for that, because in the Technology section it has 7 columns. Why is that?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you even know what you're clicking there? Those columns are showing stack exchange sites, and they change because you click the five words on the left to classify them into groups, same thing [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: @mindstormsboi yes. I know what you mean but I don't know what your point is.

Comment: All of these sections invariably have 7 rows; as a result the number of columns changes. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I don't know what each screenshot represent, you didn't give any details.

Comment: @user289905 I'd at least expect the number of columns for e.g. 'Science' to be more, instead of it showing the 'more(10)'?

Comment: @user289905 Hmm. For example, the Science section has 2 columns, but there are still 10 more unlisted sites. Why don't they be listed? Apparently there are rooms for that, because in the Technology section it has 7 columns. Is that clearer?

Comment: I'm interested why the "Professional" section is missing altogether? No love for workplace, aviation et al.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display maximum possible count of sites in footer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299608/282094), https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356514/282094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The footer displays all non-beta sites ([as far as anyone can tell, at least](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356514/165261)) in each category, in seven rows.

So the number of columns is simply the number of non-beta sites in that category (plus one for the "more" link) divided by seven, rounded up to the next whole number.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't about columns or available space.

The footer shows only the graduated site in each category.

Beta sites that didn't graduate yet are not listed by name in the footer, but you can click the "more" link to see them.